# Cloudera Twiiter Hive Query failure

Tags: twitter, cloudera, hadoop-streaming

Team,

Curious to know if anyone succeeded in executing query for Twitter Cloudera Example?

I added mentioned SerDe Jar in Beewax file resources as Jar, still I am getting the error for any query.

Query:

```
SELECT
t.retweeted_screen_name,
sum(retweets) AS total_retweets,
count(*) AS tweet_count
FROM (SELECT
retweeted_status.user.screen_name as retweeted_screen_name,
retweeted_status.text,
max(retweet_count) as retweets
FROM tweets
GROUP BY retweeted_status.user.screen_name,
retweeted_status.text) t
GROUP BY t.retweeted_screen_name
ORDER BY total_retweets DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Your query has the following error(s):

Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

```
INFO : Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 1
INFO : In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
INFO : set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=
INFO : In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
INFO : set hive.exec.reducers.max=
INFO : In order to set a constant number of reducers:
INFO : set mapreduce.job.reduces=
WARN : Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
INFO : number of splits:1
INFO : Submitting tokens for job: job_1432914212475_0002
INFO : The url to track the job: http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1432914212475_0002/
INFO : Starting Job = job_1432914212475_0002, Tracking URL = http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1432914212475_0002/
INFO : Kill Command = /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job -kill job_1432914212475_0002
INFO : Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 1
INFO : 2015-05-29 10:20:59,400 Stage-1 map = 0%, reduce = 0%
INFO : 2015-05-29 10:21:35,687 Stage-1 map = 100%, reduce = 100%
ERROR : Ended Job = job_1432914212475_0002 with errors
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved!

Don't use prebuilt SerDe Jar to download. It may be outdated.

Compile yourself!